# Ayuda con insercion PL/SQL en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

Lo que ocurre es que estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda en dos tablas y a través de cursores con parámetros hacer el calculo de un impuesto e insertar los datos en una nueva tabla llamada impuestos. Tengo tres tablas, `AUTOMOVIL`, `AVALUOS` e `IMPUESTOS`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esas serían las tablas `Automovil` y `Avaluos`. La idea es a través de un programa *PL/SQL* insertar `PLACA`, `VIGENCIA` y un `Impuesto` que se calcula al aplicar el porcentaje del impuesto al valor de la tabla `automovil`. No se si hay un error con mi lógica; pero cuando intento hacer las inserciones no deja ningún dato en la tabla `Impuestos`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el *script* que utilicé:

```
set serveroutput on
set verify off

declare

cursor a is
select marca, placa, valor
from automovil;

cursor av (marc varchar2) is
select *
from avaluos 
where marca = marc;

cursor imp is
select * from impuestos;

impu number;
pla varchar2(150);
vige number;


begin
for ra in a loop
pla := ra.placa;
  for rav in av(ra.marca) loop
    impu := ra.valor - (ra.valor * (rav.porcentaje/100));
    vige := rav.vigencia;
        for rimp in imp  loop
        insert into impuestos (placa, vigencia, impuesto)
            values (pla, vige, impu);
            commit;
            end loop;
        end loop;
           end loop;

     end;
     /
```

Me ayudan a ver ¿Dónde está el problema con el?

Answer (score 1):

El error no es de sintaxis, sin embargo resulta innecesario iterar la tabla impuestos, entonces el problema si es de logica, dado que al no tener registros la tabla impuestos, del cursor imp, jamas va a insertar datos aunque existan avaluos para las diferentes marcas de automoviles. veamos:

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR a IS
  SELECT marca,
         placa, 
         valor
    FROM automovil;

   CURSOR av (marc VARCHAR2) IS
   SELECT *
     FROM avaluos 
    WHERE marca = marc;

   --CURSOR imp IS
   --SELECT * 
   --FROM impuestos;

    impu  NUMBER;
     pla  automovil.placa%TYPE;
    vige  avaluos.vigencia%TYPE;

BEGIN

FOR ra IN a LOOP
    pla := ra.placa;
    FOR rav IN av(ra.marca) LOOP
        impu := ra.valor - (ra.valor * (rav.porcentaje/100));
        vige := rav.vigencia;
        --FOR rimp IN imp LOOP
          INSERT INTO impuestos (placa, vigencia, impuesto) 
               VALUES (pla, vige, impu);            
        --END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'Error insertando impuestos, causado por '||SQLERRM 
  || ' -- Linea: ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());       
END;
/
```

Acostumbrese tambien a usar la manejar y capturar las excepciones, si su error es de sintaxis podra ubicar el problema rapidamente. Este bloque puede mejorarse considerablemente uniendo las tablas de avaluos y automoviles, utilizando un INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, etc. segun sea el caso. Tenga en cuenta siempre utilizar tanto llave primarias como foraneas en sus tablas [normalizacion de base de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos) aunque sean ejemplos de estudio. Un ejemplo funcional de lo anterior seria:

```
DECLARE 

 CURSOR curImp IS
 SELECT at.placa, 
        av.vigencia,
        (at.valor - (at.valor * (av.porcentaje/100))) imp        
   FROM automovil at
  INNER JOIN avaluos av ON av.marca = av.marca;

 BEGIN

   FOR i IN curImp LOOP
      INSERT INTO impuestos (placa, vigencia, impuesto) 
           VALUES (i.placa, i.vigencia, i.imp);                    
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;

 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN 
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'Error insertando impuestos, causado por: 
   '||SQLERRM || ' -- Linea: ' ||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());        
 END;
```

Espero que aunque tarde la respuesta, sirva como objeto de estudio.